# boost::scoped_ptr initialization with other scoped_ptr causes issue. Is this code correct

Tags: c++, boost, scoped-ptr

I am new to boost library and trying `boost::scoped_ptr`, it states this smart pointer cannot be copied or moved. But I was playing with some code and found an issue. I was able to create new instance of `scoped_ptr` and initialize it with existing valid `scoped_ptr`. So if one of the `scoped_ptr`'s scope is over and deallocates the memory , other scoped_ptr still thinks its valid pointer and tries to access. It gave me error at runtime.

I am working on boost library version 1.66, with cygwin g++ compiler and using std=c++03 option while compiling.

```
#include<boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    boost::scoped_ptr<int> pi(new int(9));
    cout << *pi << endl;
    cout << uintptr_t(pi.get()) << endl;

    boost::scoped_ptr<int> ppi(pi.get()); // initialized with same memory pointed by pi.
    cout << *ppi << endl;                 // so ownership of same memory is with pi.
    cout << uintptr_t(ppi.get()) << endl; // as well as with ppi.

    pi.reset(new int(12)); //its previous memory location pointing to 9 is deallocated.

    cout << *ppi << endl;                  // throws garbage value.. 
    cout << uintptr_t(ppi.get()) << endl;  // shows same memory location it had previous memory shown by pi. 

    cout << *pi << endl;
    cout << uintptr_t(pi.get()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So below is the snapshot of code run after compiling fine...

```
-> g++ -std=c++03 -Wall scoped_ptr.cpp 

-> ./a.exe 
9
25769804960
9
25769804960
-2144292696
25769804960
12
25769879920
Aborted (core dumped)
```

At end of execution is shows core dump, it incorrectly displayed `-2144292696` in above run.

Also I checked `boost::scoped_ptr` was able to assign it to pointer
`int * p = pi.get()` statement compiles fine (should this work?)

Is above operation initializing `scoped_pt`r with other `scoped_ptr` valid?

Comment: Are you restricted to c++03? That's an ancient standard and c++11 features std::shared_ptr, std::unique_ptr and std::weak_ptr which may be very well suited to your problem.

Comment: wanted to make sure I am using old compiler and boost library. Also as I said I am new to boost, so just playing with it and learning.

Answer (score 1):

> Is above operation initializing `scoped_ptr` with other `scoped_ptr` valid?

No. [Boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) reads:

> `explicit scoped_ptr(T * p = 0); // never throws`
>
> Constructs a `scoped_ptr`, storing a copy of `p`, which must have been allocated via a C++ `new` expression or be `0`.

When you initialize one smart pointer with a raw pointer that is held by another smart one, you do not transfer ownership, you just make a copy of raw a pointer. Hence, that pointer will be `delete`d several times, which is undefined behavior.

What your code does is essentially this:

```
int* p = new int;
delete p;  // when you call pi.reset()
delete p;  // when ppi goes out of scope
```

`.get()` returns the stored raw pointer. It doesn't check its validity.

To transfer ownership, you should move-assign smart pointer itself. Simple example with `std::unique_ptr` and C++11:

```
auto p = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int);
// auto p1 = std::unique_ptr<int>(p.get()); // same error
auto p2 = std::move(p); // fine, transfers ownership from p to p2; 
                        // p will not delete the raw pointer it previously held
```

`boost::scoped_ptr` does not support ownership transfer.